# Kendo Treemap Tooltip in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, treemap

does anybody know how to create a tooltip on hover for a Kendo treemap?
Something like this but for ASP.NET MVC:

[Kendo Treemap Tooltip](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/treemap/how-to/show-treemap-tooltip)

I already tried this, but when i move the mouse over the fields nothing appears..

```
 $("#treemap").kendoTooltip({
    filter: ".k-leaf,.k-treemap-title",
    position: "top",
    content: function (e) {
      var treemap = $("#treemap").data("kendoTreeMap");
      var item = treemap.dataItem(e.target.closest(".k-treemap-tile"));
      return item.name + ": " + item.value;
    }
  });
```

When i use the jquery function i can write the right values of each Treemap fiel in the javascript console.

```
 $("#treeMap").on("mouseenter", ".k-leaf", function () {
    var item = $("#treeMap").data("kendoTreeMap").dataItem($(this).closest(".k-treemap-tile"));
    var text = "Name: " + item.Name + "  Value: " + item.Value;
 console.log(text);
```

Is it possible to use this function and create a Kendo tooltip with these values?

Comment: What does `treemap`/`item` contain in your `kendoTooltip` definition?

Comment: I don't know.. this is just the code from the demo

Comment: The above demo is working for me..

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Post up your `.cshtml` code for the Treemap control.

Answer (score 0):

@Sandman: here is the code..

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeMap()
      .Name("treeMap")
      .Theme("Material")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Read(read => read
              .Action("GetMyTreeMapData", "Home")
          )
          .Model(m => m.Children("Items"))
      )
      .ValueField("Value")
      .TextField("Name")
      .Events(events => events
            .ItemCreated("onItemCreated")
            .DataBound("onDataBound")
      )

      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:800px; font-size: 12px;" })
```